# Floating multiple tables

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-float

I'm a little stuck floating my tables.. I keep ending up with a gap between two tables which I'd like to remove. Could anyone explain how I can remove the gaps between the two vertical tables?

Here is an example of what I'm seeing and what isn't correct (The gaps):

[image]

HTML:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link href="css/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<table class="spec-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="spec-name">
            <td>Technical details</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">TV tuner integrated</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">N</td>
        <tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">Cooling type</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">active</td>
        <tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">Form factor</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">ATX</td>
        <tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">Number of processors installed</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">1</td>
        <tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">Fill rate</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">28.8 billion texels/sec</td>
        <tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">Graphics adapter family</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">NVIDIA</td>
        <tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">Maximum operating temperature</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">98 °C</td>
        <tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="spec-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="spec-name">
            <td>Processor</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">Graphics processor</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">GeForce GT 640</td>
        <tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">Maximum resolution</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">2560 x 1600 pixels</td>
        <tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">Graphics processor family</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">NVIDIA</td>
        <tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">Processor clock speed</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">901 MHz</td>
        <tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">Shader clock</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">1802 MHz</td>
        <tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">Graphics adapter RAMDAC</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">400 MHz</td>
        <tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">Parallel processing technology support</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">N</td>
        <tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">Maximum analog resolution</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">2048 x 1536 pixels</td>
        <tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">Maximum digital resolution</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">2560 x 1600 pixels</td>
        <tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">Stream processors</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">384</td>
        <tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="spec-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="spec-name">
            <td>Memory</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">Discrete graphics adapter memory</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">2048 MB</td>
        <tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">Graphics adapter memory type</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">DDR3-SDRAM</td>
        <tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">Memory bus</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">128 bit</td>
        <tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">Memory clock speed</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">1782 MHz</td>
        <tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">Memory bandwidth (max)</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">28.5 GB/s</td>
        <tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="spec-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="spec-name">
            <td>System requirements</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">Mac compatibility</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">N</td>
        <tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">Minimum system power supply</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">350 W</td>
        <tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="spec-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="spec-name">
            <td>Ports & interfaces</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">Interface type</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">PCI Express 3.0</td>
        <tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">DVI-D ports quantity</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">2</td>
        <tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">VGA (D-Sub) ports quantity</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">1</td>
        <tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">DVI port</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">2</td>
        <tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">HDMI ports quantity</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">1</td>
        <tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="spec-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="spec-name">
            <td>Weight & dimensions</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">Number of slots</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">2</td>
        <tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="spec-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="spec-name">
            <td>Video</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">PhysX</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">Yes</td>
        <tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">CUDA</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">Yes</td>
        <tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">DirectX version</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">11</td>
        <tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">Shader model version</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">5.0</td>
        <tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">OpenGL version</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">4.2</td>
        <tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">HDMI</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">Yes</td>
        <tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">HDMI version</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">1.4a</td>
        <tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">Full HD</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">Yes</td>
        <tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">Dual Link DVI</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">Yes</td>
        <tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">HDCP</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">Yes</td>
        <tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">CUDA cores</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">384</td>
        <tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">3D Vision</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">Y</td>
        <tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="spec-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="spec-name">
            <td>Operating system/software</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">Windows operating systems supported</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">Yes</td>
        <tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">Mac operating systems supported</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">N</td>
        <tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">Linux operating systems supported</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">Yes</td>
        <tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="spec-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="spec-name">
            <td>Packaging content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="spec-features">
            <td class="spec-features-name">User guide</td>
            <td class="spec-features-value">Yes</td>
        <tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    font-family: Helvetica;
}
body {
    width: 700px;
}
.spec-table {
    font-size: 11px;
    width: 330px;
    float: left;
}
.spec-table .spec-name {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #373333;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.spec-table > tbody > .spec-features {
    color: #4B4B4B;
    width: 60%;
}
.spec-table .spec-features-name {
    padding-left: 10px;
    background: #eee;
    height: 15px;
}
.spec-table .spec-features-value {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
tr > td:first-child {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle with my code in it: http://jsfiddle.net/markasoftware/Na7KB/

Comment: Isn't the empty rule for `.table-container` unnecessary?

Comment: Yep it is indeed, I forgot to remove that one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that by floating the table, "one row" is always the same height.
If you want them clean on the left and on the right you have to wrap the left an the right part in seperate boxes and then float them.

```
<div id="left">
    <!-- All your left tables-->
    <table class="spec-table">
        ...
    </table>
    ...
</div>
<div id="right">
    <!-- All your right tables -->
    <table class="spec-table">
        ...
    </table>
    ...
</div>
```

And also adjust the css

```
#left, #right {
    float: left;
}
.spec-table {
    font-size: 11px;
    width: 330px;
}
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AQpG6/

Comment: Yep that's better indeed, there is only one thing I forgot to mention.. I fetch all these data from an XML sheet from a third party site. So I can't really separate the tables

Comment: Why can't you do that? If you got some sort of an array with your data then you can loop trough and arange the html exactly the way you want.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate ? here is a copy of my code http://pastebin.com/RZJkEAdF

Comment: Just excluded the important part of the file and added some untested code. http://pastebin.com/yhQPfDBS

Answer (score 0):

Do it as facebook does it in their timeline. Use float left and float right appropriately. Of course you need to know the height of each table respectively. You could do it with JavaScript and two classes for left and right.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge some tables to show them without gap

The HTML hoes like this

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="6.css">
</head>


<body>

<table class="spec-table">
<tbody>
    <tr class="spec-name">
        <td>Technical details</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">TV tuner integrated</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">N</td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">Cooling type</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">active</td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">Form factor</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">ATX</td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">Number of processors installed</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">1</td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">Fill rate</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">28.8 billion texels/sec</td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">Graphics adapter family</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">NVIDIA</td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">Maximum operating temperature</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">98 °C</td>
    <tr>

            <tr class="spec-name">
        <td>Memory</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">Discrete graphics adapter memory</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">2048 MB</td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">Graphics adapter memory type</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">DDR3-SDRAM</td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">Memory bus</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">128 bit</td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">Memory clock speed</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">1782 MHz</td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">Memory bandwidth (max)</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">28.5 GB/s</td>
    <tr>


            <tr class="spec-name">
        <td>Weight & dimensions</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">Number of slots</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">2</td>
    <tr>


            <tr class="spec-name">
        <td>Operating system/software</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">Windows operating systems supported</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">Yes</td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">Mac operating systems supported</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">N</td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">Linux operating systems supported</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">Yes</td>
    <tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table class="spec-table">
<tbody>
    <tr class="spec-name">
        <td>Processor</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">Graphics processor</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">GeForce GT 640</td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">Maximum resolution</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">2560 x 1600 pixels</td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">Graphics processor family</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">NVIDIA</td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">Processor clock speed</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">901 MHz</td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">Shader clock</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">1802 MHz</td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">Graphics adapter RAMDAC</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">400 MHz</td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">Parallel processing technology support</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">N</td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">Maximum analog resolution</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">2048 x 1536 pixels</td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">Maximum digital resolution</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">2560 x 1600 pixels</td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">Stream processors</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">384</td>
    <tr>


            <tr class="spec-name">
        <td>System requirements</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">Mac compatibility</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">N</td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">Minimum system power supply</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">350 W</td>
    <tr>
</tbody>


    <tr class="spec-name">
        <td>Ports & interfaces</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">Interface type</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">PCI Express 3.0</td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">DVI-D ports quantity</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">2</td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">VGA (D-Sub) ports quantity</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">1</td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">DVI port</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">2</td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">HDMI ports quantity</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">1</td>
    <tr>

            <tr class="spec-name">
        <td>Video</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">PhysX</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">Yes</td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">CUDA</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">Yes</td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">DirectX version</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">11</td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">Shader model version</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">5.0</td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">OpenGL version</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">4.2</td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">HDMI</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">Yes</td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">HDMI version</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">1.4a</td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">Full HD</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">Yes</td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">Dual Link DVI</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">Yes</td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">HDCP</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">Yes</td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">CUDA cores</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">384</td>
    <tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">3D Vision</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">Y</td>
    <tr>


             <tr class="spec-name">
        <td>Packaging content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spec-features">
        <td class="spec-features-name">User guide</td>
        <td class="spec-features-value">Yes</td>
    <tr>

</tbody>
</table>



</body>
</html>
```